VARCHAR(MAX) does not hold all values
I am building a comma-separated string for a single column's value that I will then pass to an OPENQUERY so that I can optimize my query (smaller left table, very large right table).
But my problem is with building the string. The following does not pull all the values from the table.
DECLARE @VAR VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @VAR = (SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(mu.colName AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ''''',''''') 
               FROM tableName mu)

The tableName has around 15,000 rows for the ColName. I was under the impression that VARCHAR(MAX) should be able to hold all these values since VARCHAR(MAX) has an upper limit of 2 GB. The values of colName are all INT's.
How I know that not all values are being returned? I see half of the values int the variable which I manually verified. The other half are not being returned inside of the VARCHAR(MAX) variable. The DATALENGTH(@VAR) IS 193K Bytes which is well below the 2 GB limit. If VARCHAR(MAX) cannot hold all the values, then what other data type can I use?

Solution
Someone struggling with this may not be able to pose the question again  due to moderators on this site, so I am posting it my solution here. Since openquery has a limit of 8Kb, it will not fit in a very large string. Solution would be to loop around all records and pass 100/200 values at a time that would fit into the 8KB OPENQUERY limit.

How are you determining it doesn't store all the values?

I can't replicate your problem: db<>fiddle

The string_agg function should not have a trailing comma, but in this case, there's always a trailing comma and just looking at the number of records it returns, it feels more like in the 100's rather than 15k that I expect to see.

Remember that the SSMS(if you're using it) has a limitation to show characters which is ~ 43K chars. So better to run a query and save the data into a file and check.

Try adding SELECT DATALENGTH(@VAR)

"The string_agg function should not have a trailing comma, but in this case, there's always a trailing comma" that isn't how it works either. I suggest providing a [mre] here.

Wait... STRING_AGG doesn't exist on SQL Server 2016; is this a CLR function?

When I use a EXEC ATsqlstring (where ATsqlstring is something like select * from OPENQUERY(linked_server_name, 'select * from ls_table_name where remote_col_name in '( ''''' + atVAR + ''''')'')', it fails with "........2740786,2740865,' is an invalid identifier which leads me to believe that the string is getting truncated.

Do not forget, OPENQUERY is limited to 8,000 characters.

Are you sure you don't have " double quotes instead of '' two single quotes there?
